# My Tkinter login form isn't working in other devices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a login form in Tkinter, I've used Google Sheets API to verify my user name and password only with sheets, It works fine in my desktop and other computers, but It is not working on my laptop (it seems that is has no connection with internet google sheets or something like that), my laptop was using windows 8 so I thought it was the problem so I've installed windows 10 but is not working, How should I solve it?, thanks

Comment: Is your laptop connected to the internet while this happens?

Comment: I don't think the problem is caused by tkinter. If you agree, you might want to remove the `tkinter` tag.

Comment: Given that this works on other devices but your laptop, I don't think the issue is caused by the sheets api. As per @CoolCloud mentioned, there might be connection issues with the device. Try connecting it via LAN cable to exclude connection issues. Also, you can remove `google-sheets` as tag as it doesn't seem to cause the problem. This might be network/proxy related issue.

Comment: Done guys, I've removed all tags mentioned, @NaziA I also think it was the issue, I've tried with cable and wifi connection but nothing, and just now for some reason is working properly, it's weird, maybe there were some network permissions issues. Thanks guys

Comment: Thank you for confirming @Paul, glad you were able to fix your issue.